# Simpler way of proving series convergence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine whether the following series converges $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left (\frac{n^4}{n^4 + 2}\right)^{n^5-3}.$$

I've found convergence using the root criterion in the following way.

$\sqrt[n]{ \left (\frac{n^4}{n^4 + 2}\right)^{n^5-3}} = \left (\frac{n^4}{n^4 + 2}\right)^{n^4-3/n} \leq \left (\frac{n^4}{n^4 + 2}\right)^{n^4-1} =  \frac{1}{(1 + \frac{2}{n^4})^{n^4-1}} \to \frac{1}{e^2} < 1$

My question is if there is an easier way to see this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

$$(1 - \frac{2}{n^4+2})^{n^4 + 2} \le e^{-2}  $$

$$\frac{n^4}{n^4 + 2} \lt 1$$